# Difference between document and text/html content type

Tags: javascript, ajax

Wanted to know the difference between *document* and *text/html* content types. I noticed that call to a view was made and I could see a response in the *document* type call but no response was seen in *text/html* type call.

In the below image, if you notice, we have made same call twice, one is of document type and another is of text/html type. I am getting the response in document type call but no response in text/html type call. So just wanted to understand the difference between these two content types' behaviors.

[image: Calls]

Comment: Hard to make much sense about what you are asking without more context

Comment: Updated the question please review. @charlietfl

Comment: Can you look into the header section of these two requests to see if there is any difference ? It is possible that these are two different kind of response are received for the same url request. 
Look into the headers.

Comment: Got it. The Request Headers were different. Thank you. @RaghvendraKumar

Comment: Hi there, I am wondering the same thing, except the problem is that I am getting a 404 error on the second request (the text/html) one, do you have any idea what the reason could be?

Comment: @Winter Try checking the initiator of the call. The second call may have been initiated by any different function. When you hover over the text in the initiator columns you will find the stack of functions through which the request came.